# Custom styled MUI IconButton does not work with tooltop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, position, tooltip, styled-components

I have styled IconButton so it looks like I need the problem I have right now is that when I use ToolTip it does not appear near to my button but instead in top left corner of the page.

What I do wrong?

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

export const Colors = ['#58b864', '#91d704', '#9ad436', '#fd9828', '#ff7826', '#fc4a41', '#e01f1f', '#4065ac', '#4065ac', '#4065ac', '#4065ac'];

const Button = (props, Component) => {
    const { color, greyed, children, className, icon, ...other } = props;

    const StyledButton = styled(IconButton)(({ theme }) => ({
        borderRadius: '18%',
        height: '26px',
        width: '26px',
        fontSize: '15px',
        backgroundColor: greyed ? '#293357' : color,
        color: greyed ? (theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#63697d' : '#bebebe') : '#fff' , //?  : theme.palette.grey[50]
        '& svg': {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        '&:hover': {
            color: '#fff',
            backgroundColor: color,
            filter: icon ? 'none' : 'brightness(1.2)',
            cursor: icon ? 'default' : 'pointer'
        },
        '&.Mui-disabled': {
            backgroundColor: '#293357',
            color: '#666979'
        }
    }));

    return (
        <StyledButton
            {...other}
            component={icon ? null : motion.div}
            whileHover={{
                scale: 1.1,
                transition: { duration: 0.3 }
            }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
        >
            {children}
        </StyledButton>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

Update:
I have found out that this work with tooltip:

```
const properties = ['color', 'greyed', 'icon']

const Button = styled(IconButton, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => !properties.includes(prop)})
    (({ theme, color, greyed, icon }) => ({
    borderRadius: '18%',
    height: '26px',
    width: '26px',
    fontSize: '15px',
    backgroundColor: greyed ? '#293357' : color,
    color: greyed ? (theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#63697d' : '#bebebe') : '#fff' ,
    '& svg': {
        fontSize: '16px'
    },
    '&:hover': {
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: color,
        filter: icon ? 'none' : 'brightness(1.2)',
        cursor: icon ? 'default' : 'pointer'
    },
    '&.Mui-disabled': {
        backgroundColor: '#293357',
        color: '#666979'
    }
}));
```

But then I don't understand how to globally apply animations from motion framer. Please help, what do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I add `position:"relative"` try it.

```
      const StyledButton = styled(IconButton)(({ theme }) => ({
position:"relative",
        borderRadius: '18%',
        height: '26px',
        width: '26px',
        fontSize: '15px',
        backgroundColor: greyed ? '#293357' : color,
        color: greyed ? (theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#63697d' : '#bebebe') : '#fff' , //?  : theme.palette.grey[50]
        '& svg': {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        '&:hover': {
            color: '#fff',
            backgroundColor: color,
            filter: icon ? 'none' : 'brightness(1.2)',
            cursor: icon ? 'default' : 'pointer'
        },
        '&.Mui-disabled': {
            backgroundColor: '#293357',
            color: '#666979'
        }
    }));
```